# Cannot import name 'WORKSPACE_EXTENSION' from 'jupyterlab_server'

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

After updating to the most recent `jupyter_server` (1.13.1), when I enter

```
jupyter lab
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-lab", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.labapp import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .labapp import LabApp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jupyterlab_server import WORKSPACE_EXTENSION, LabServerApp, slugify
ImportError: cannot import name 'WORKSPACE_EXTENSION' from 'jupyterlab_server' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/__init__.py)
```

How do I correct this? Do I have incompatabe package versions installed?

---

```sh
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 21 2021, 03:23:42) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]
```

```sh
jupyter-client                    7.1.0
jupyter-core                      4.9.1
jupyter-kite                      2.0.2
jupyter-server                    1.13.1
jupyter-server-mathjax            0.2.3
jupyterlab                        3.2.5
jupyterlab-git                    0.34.0
jupyterlab-kite                   2.0.2
jupyterlab-pygments               0.1.2
jupyterlab-server                 2.10.0
```

Comment: Downgrade to `jupyterlab-server<2.10.0` or wait for hotfix in `2.10.1` - on the way!

Comment: Subscribe here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab_server/pull/230 to get notified of 2.10.1 release.

Comment: On PyPI since 25 minutes: https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab-server/2.10.1/

Comment: @krassowski That all counts as an answer that I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jupyterlab-server` version `2.10.0` had an unintentional breaking change which was hotfixed in `2.10.1`. To fix this issue upgrade to `2.10.1` (or newer):

```sh
pip install jupyterlab-server>=2.10.1
```

conda installs using `conda-forge` should not be affected as `2.10.0` was never published there.